# Run Cucumber JUnit5 via maven surefire

Tags: cucumber, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run cucumber 7.8.0 with JUnit 5.
These are my dependencies:

- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:7.8.0
- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.8.0
- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.8.0
- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:7.8.0
- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:1.8.2
- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.8.2
- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.8.2
- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console:1.8.2
- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2
- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.core.options.Constants.FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.core.options.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("cucumber/mytest.feature")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example.steps")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "classpath:cucumber/mytest.feature")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

I would like to run cucumber using maven-surefire-plugin (version: 2.22.2), but it says no junit test is found. When I debug, it seems that SelectClasspathResource is never loaded.

Can someone please advice?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried upgrading everything, including the Maven plugin to the latest version?

Comment: Hi @M.P.Korstanje, yes. I have updated maven surefire to 3.0.0. It doesn't help also.

Comment: You probably don't have your directory structure quite right. You can use https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton to get started.

Comment: Thanks @M.P.Korstanje, it works fine. I need to add junit-platform-suite.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below dependencies to your pom.xml file:

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
  <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>5.9.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
Next, you need to configure surefire plugin as follows, remember to change the value in the <test> tag to your runner file path from source root :

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
            <test>com.learning.springboot.first.time.runners.runner.java</test>
                </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```